# Displaying 2 different values in Vega Text Field

Tags: vega

I would like to use 2 values in a Vega Text Mark, but there is little documentation for this old version of Vega (Vega 1.5.0).

I would like it to show up something resembling: Name: Value, but I cant find a way to get it to work.

This is my current definition JSON implementation, and it shows the text fine, I just can't get it to show another

`"text": { "field": "data.name" },`

I have tried something like this to no avail, any advice?

`"text": {"field": "data.name", "field": "data.value" },`

Have now also tried using the transform calculate as suggested, using it as such within the transform block. And referring to tooltip in the text field. This has also not worked.

```
{
"calculate": "data.name + ':' + data.value", "as": "tooltip"
}
```

Conclusion: In Vega 1.5.0 this is seemingly not possible, Following suggestions has not resulted in the desired solution. If you are looking to do this in such an old version of Vega, I would recommend you update Vega to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Use a calculate transform to concat your text values and use that new field.

Comment: Does the new field need to be wrapped in an encode block? Or to just reference it normally?

Comment: Share your full spec. Why are you using such an old version of Vega?

Comment: Also, usually, the syntax is datum.fieldname.

Comment: The entire spec is over 1000 lines long, which is why i only provided info for this bit. And in my scenario it is data as thats just how it was defined.

Comment: Have you tried the datum syntax? That is how you access your data in Vega regardless of how you have "defined" it.

Comment: I dont understand where you believe the datum syntax will help, as in where should i use datum. Per the vega wiki, you can name your dataset whatever you want as a String, which is what has been done here.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the dataset name.  Change your code to the following: {
"calculate": "datum.name + ':' + datum.value", "as": "tooltip"
}

Comment: I have tried this to no avail, i have tried referencing the tooltip as tooltip and datum.tooltip. I think this is just something that simply isnt possible in this version of vega.

Comment: Are you using Vega or Vega-Lite?  In Vega, the transform is called "formula" rather than calculate.

Comment: I am using Regular Vega, and I have also tried formula aswell as calculate. I am going to put this question to bed as unsolved, as I have found an alternate solution that does not involve my Vega spec. This is seemingly just something that is not possible in this old Vega version and that's fully understandable. Thanks for the suggestions though!